# What distribution has the best cross compatibility on Amazon AWS Graviton?

Tags: amazon-web-services, arm64, abi, aws-graviton

I am looking for the best Linux distribution on Amazon AWS Graviton for compiling an application.  Most important to me is that my application will run on the most AWS Arm64 distributions.  It dynamically links against C/C++ runtime libraries and everything else will be statically linked in.

For x86-64, I have had very good luck with a Centos 7 based linux distribution, and I have not found any binary compatibility issues on other distributions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Amazon Linux](https://github.com/amazonlinux/amazon-linux-2023) has very good compatibility with everything related to AWS Graviton. C/C++ apps are a different beast, so I recommend you check the [guide for this type of apps](https://github.com/aws/aws-graviton-getting-started/blob/main/c-c++.md).

Comment: I ended up using a version of manylinux 2014 targeting aarch64.  It runs successfully on both Amazon and Google hardware.